# The meaning of モン in 上手いモンでしょう

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

The main characters younger sister showed him some scribbles she had done in her textbook and then said 「上手いモンでしょう」.

My question is whether it is [definition 5 here](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%89%A9?dic=daijisen&oid=18293900) or whether モン refers to the scribble itself.

Answer (score 2):

It is definition 5-㋑.

「[上手]{うま}いモンでしょう」 is, in my own words, an "**exclamatory rhetorical question**".

= ***"Looks awesome, doesn't it?"***

The "statement" form using this 「もん」 would be 「上手いもんだ/もんです」.

So, 「モン」 does not refer to the scribble itself.